# Encontrar el mayor y menor alfabeticamente

Tags: java

En clase me piden en un apartado de un extenso ejercicio lo siguiente encontrar el mayor y el menor de un Array de forma alfabetica. Y el ejercicio lo resumire (porque dentro de este hay mas apartados) en lo siguiente:

```
import java.util.Collections;

public class Ejercicio3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] color = new String[5];
    

    //A) Añade 5 elementos

    color[0] = "Morado";
    color[1] = "Negro";
    color[2] = "Azul";
    color[3] = "Rojo";
    color[4] = "Blanco";

    //E) Encuentra el mayor y el menor alfabeticamente
```

En el apartado E he intentado lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("Ordenamos de menor a mayor el Array: ");
    
    Arrays.sort(color,Collections.reverseOrder()); //Ordenado de forma inversa (se podria no hacer de forma inversa pero bueno, por probar.
    
    for(String s : color) {
        System.out.println(s);
        } // Esto lo tuve que buscar sinceramente para saber como imprimir el array de 
          // forma ordenada pero no lo comprendo. 
    
    
    System.out.println("El menor es: ");
    for(int i=0;i<color.length;)
    {
        System.out.println(color[i]);
        
        break;
    } // Aqui lo que hice fue crear un bucle y hacer break para que me saque el primer dato solo, que seria el menor en este caso.
    
    System.out.println("El Mayor es: ");
    for(int i=0;i<color.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(color[i]);
    } //En este caso, quiero sacar el ultimo valor, que es el mayor, pero me falta lógica y no logro sacarlo.
```

Perdonad las molestias. Seguramente haya una forma más facil de lograr esto (como con el CompareTo) pero el profesor nos ha pedido otra forma, para aprender lógica(supong) y ha escrito un código diferente en la pizarra.

Pero quiero saber si de esta forma se puede lograr. Es mi forma y quiero saber si es salvable de alguna forma jajaja.

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las soluciones que te dieron son válidas y son bastante prácticas, pero no son las más eficientes. Claro que para la cantidad de datos que estás manejando es irrelevante, pero si el arreglo se hace considerablemente grande, empiezan a aparecer los problemas, y es bueno que la tengas en mente.

Una ordenación utilizando `Arrays.sort()` como te plantean en las otras respuestas tiene una complejidad computacional de `O(nlog(n))` cuando en realidad el problema que planteas se puede hacer muy fácil en `O(n)`.

Para ello, empieza por crear una variable que guardará el mínimo `min` y otra variable que guardará el máximo `max`. A estas variables les vas a asignar el primer elemento del arreglo. Luego, simplemente vas a iterar por todos los valores del arreglo. Si el valor actual es mayor que `max`, sustituyes el valor de `max` por ese valor. Si el valor actual es menor que `min`, sustituyes el valor actual por ese valor.

Como último detalle, puedes comparar dos `String` según su orden lexicográfico usando `string1.compareTo(string2)`. Si el `string1 > string2` entonces el resultado será un número mayor que cero. Si el `string1 < string2` el resultado será un número menor que cero. Si son iguales el resultado será `0`.

Una posible implementación es:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] color = new String[5];
        color[0] = "Morado";
        color[1] = "Negro";
        color[2] = "Azul";
        color[3] = "Rojo";
        color[4] = "Blanco";


        String min = color[0];
        String max = color[0];

        for (int i = 1; i < color.length; i++) {
            if (color[i].compareTo(min) < 0) {
                min = color[i];
            }

            if (color[i].compareTo(max) > 0) {
                max = color[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.printf("El menor elemento es %s y el máximo es %s.", min, max);
    }
}
```

Nota que a pesar de que el código no es tan corto como el resto, la solución si es la más eficiente a este problema.

Comment: Te agradezco la aclaración y la ayuda. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tiempo en la publicación, un saludo.

Answer (score 2):

Podrias usar solo [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) para ordenar alfabeticamente lo valores de tu array el menor se encontrara en la primer indice de tu array el cual sera `0` y el mayor en el ultimo indice el cual sera igual al `tamaño de tu array -1`

```
import java.util.Arrays;


    public class Ejemplo{
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String []color=new String[5];
    
       color[0] = "Morado";
        color[1] = "Azul";
        color[2] = "Negro";
        color[3] = "Rojo";
        color[4] = "Verde";
    
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(color));
     Arrays.sort(color);
     System.out.println(color[0]);//menor
     System.out.println(color[color.length-1]);//mayor
        
    }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias Dramaturgo por tu respuesta y tu tiempo para ayudarme. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Para ordenar el Array alfabeticamente puedes usar simplemente

```
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Al ordenarlo puede obtener el mayor y el menor mediante el primer y el último indice de los elementos en el arreglo:

```
String primerElemento = array[0];
String últimoElemento = array[array.length-1];
```

Por ejemplo:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String[] color = new String[5];
    //A) Añade 5 elementos
    color[0] = "Morado";
    color[1] = "Negro";
    color[2] = "Azul";
    color[3] = "Rojo";
    color[4] = "Blanco";

    Arrays.sort(color);    

     String primerElemento = array[0];
     String ultimoElemento = array[array.length-1];

    System.out.println("El menor elemento es: " + primerElemento );
    System.out.println("El mayor elemento es: " + ultimoElemento );

}
```

la salida sería:

```
El menor elemento es: Azul
El mayor elemento es: Rojo
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tiempo en ella, un saludo. De verdad lo agradezco enormemente.